# How do VPS cloud providers prevent their ipv4 public address from running out?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, ip-address, vps, digital-ocean

I am currently using digitalocean. I am pleased to see that my VM was assigned a public IP address. Given the limited number of ipv4 ip address, how do VPS cloud providers like digitalocean, Azure, AWS prevent their ipv4 IP address from running out? This is particularly so today when any developer can apply for a VM for testing. Do VPS providers use some kind of protocol like NAT to save IP address?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, and is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: how do I move it to some other more relevant stack exchange website? Not sure if there is a relevant one. I cannot delete the question as there is an answer already.

Comment: You might consider superuser, but I'm not sure it's on topic there either. And as far as the answer goes: you marked it as an accepted answer, yet it's based on opinion on how cloud vendors work, and made an assumption about dns vs ip address that isn't always true.

Comment: @David Makogon, my mistake. Don't have the expert knowledge to know whether answer is right or wrong. Sounds right, so I marked it. On second thoughts, I unmarked it after reading your comments. Would you mind providing a more correct answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about Digital Ocean, but certainly [Amazon Web Services](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) and [Microsoft Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=41653) own IPv4 ranges. So they just allocate you an IP from their owned range when you spin up an instance. Digital Ocean either own some IP space too, or else lease it from somebody else.

When your instance has it's own public IP, NAT isn't involved. You can be sure that you're the only one who's using that IP.

So although the IPv4 range is certainly depleted, you can be sure that these companies aren't going to allocate you a public IP unless they can afford to. Microsoft and Amazon are most definitely going to make sure they have more than enough free IPs available for themselves before even thinking about customers needs.

But, it's always better to rely on DNS names instead of IPs because IPs are changeable.

Comment: This is your opinion about how companies deal with their IP address space ranges. And your comment about relying on DNS names instead of IP addresses is not always true, especially when needing to whitelist specific IP addresses.